# Infinite loop in guess-the-number program

Tags: python

Pretty much noob in programming here, with about 3 weeks in mostly theory.
I'm trying to write a basic guess-the-number program.
I am not sure why I am getting infinite loop so wanted to check with more skilled people.
Using PyCharm to write script.

```
import random
secret_number = random.randint(1, 100)
guess_number = int(input('What is your guess?'))
lives = 6

while secret_number != guess_number:
        if secret_number > guess_number:
                print('Try higher')
                lives -= 1
        elif secret_number < guess_number:
                print('Try lower')
                lives -= 1
        else:
                print('You guessed the number!')
```

When I press shift + f10 program either "burns" through all 6 iterations of "lives" strings or ends up in infinite loop. Why?

Comment: Neither `secret_number` nor `guess_number` can change within the body of the loop, so every iteration will always do the same thing.

Comment: you only `read` the secret number once outside the `while` loop. At each iteration in the while, you need to get a new number from user.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is on `secret_number` and `guess_number`, and none of them changes in the loop, so as soon as you don't find it at first try, you'll have an infitite loop.

You may ask the user **in** the loop and use the condition on `lives` too

```
import random

secret_number = random.randint(1, 100)
lives = 6
while lives > 0:
    lives -= 1
    guess_number = int(input('What is your guess: '))
    if secret_number > guess_number:
        print('Try higher')
        lives -= 1
    elif secret_number < guess_number:
        print('Try lower')
        lives -= 1
    else:
        print('You guessed the number!')
        break
```

Comment: Thank you very much people!
Managed to sort it out, yay!